# Global variables issue in my JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

1. Why does the alert("2") pop up first?
2. Why can't I create global variables c and ctx?
3. How do I create these two global variables so I can use them in another function e.g. drawCircle();

   ```
   //html5
   //<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
   // ...
   //<canvas id="can" width="500" height="500></canvas>

   //my.js
   //The working code
   window.onload = drawRectangle;
   function drawRectangle() {
       var c = document.getElementById("can");
       var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
       ctx.fillStyle = "green";
       ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 100);
   }  


   //my.js 
   //The non-working code 
   //alert function just for debugging  
   window.onload = init;
   var c;
   var ctx;
   function init() {
       alert("1");
       c = document.getElementById("can");
       ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   }
   function drawRectangle() {
       alert("2");
       ctx.fillStyle = "green";
       ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 100);
   }
   drawRectangle();
   ```

   If I create c and ctx as global variables in the same HTML5 file, 
   and it works as it should. Why does not work on an external javascript file?

Comment: It is better to call "init" function within "drawRectangle". Maybe when window.onload is being invoked the global variables are not declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days reading, the following are explanations why the rectangle will not be drawn.

1. While loading the page, drawRectangle() is invoked. However, variables c and ctx have not been initialized. Therefore, it will not draw the rectangle.
2. Until finished loading the page, init() function is invoked, the variables c and ctx have also not been initialized. As a result, the rectangle will not be drawn.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `drawRectangle()` before `init` has run. It uses the global variables as expected, but they are still uninitialised. Move the call into the `init` function:

```
var c;
var ctx;
function init() {
    alert("1");
    c = document.getElementById("can");
    ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    drawRectangle();
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
function drawRectangle() {
    alert("2");
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 100);
}
window.onload = init;
```

After doing that, you can (and should) avoid the global variables and simply pass the necessary values by argument:

```
function init() {
    var c = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    drawRectangle(ctx);
//                ^^^
}
function drawRectangle(ctx) {
//                     ^^^
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 200, 100);
}
window.onload = init;
```